# isAnnotationPresent() is not working with @Repeatable annotations

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

It turns out that calling method.isAnnotationPresent() is not working properly if you use repeatable annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange thing is that it is working in case you use only one annotation, but not working if you put more than one.
The problem is that if you have more than one annotation there, method actually has one annotation that contains all repeatable annotations (the one stated in @Repeatable value)

Comment: That is because multiple annotations are wrapped in a container annotation. In the `@Schedule` example in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html you would see that `isAnnotationPresent` would be true for the `@Schedules` annotation once there is more than one. It's just a compiler trick, you still can't actually have multiple annotations.